# Tic Tac Toe win conditions not activating correctly

Tags: java

I asked a question a while back. After much code rewriting, my tic tac toe is looking good, except for one glaring problem. When I  try to play, the win conditions seemingly activate at random - I'll have x - o - x in a line and say "Player X won!", but when I have o - o - o it won't detect a win. Draw works ok though.

Win Conditions code:

```
 // win conditions. if true, set win==true; else set win==false
            if (square[0].getText().equals(square[1].getText())
                    && square[1].getText().equals(square[2].getText())
                    != square[0].getText().isEmpty()) {
                    win = true;}

            if (square[3].getText().equals(square[4].getText())
                    && square[4].getText().equals(square[5].getText())
                    != square[3].getText().isEmpty()) {
                    win = true;}

            if (square[6].getText().equals(square[7].getText())
                    && square[7].getText().equals(square[8].getText())
                    != square[6].getText().isEmpty()) {
                    win = true;}

            if (square[0].getText().equals(square[3].getText())
                    && square[3].getText().equals(square[6].getText())
                    != square[0].getText().isEmpty()) {
                    win = true;}

            if (square[1].getText().equals(square[4].getText())
                    && square[4].getText().equals(square[7].getText())
                    != square[1].getText().isEmpty()) {
                    win = true;}

            if (square[2].getText().equals(square[5].getText())
                    && square[5].getText().equals(square[8].getText())
                    != square[2].getText().isEmpty()) {
                    win = true;}

            if (square[0].getText().equals(square[4].getText())
                    && square[4].getText().equals(square[8].getText())
                    != square[0].getText().isEmpty()) {
                    win = true;}

            if (square[6].getText().equals(square[4].getText())
                    && square[4].getText().equals(square[2].getText())
                    != square[6].getText().isEmpty()) {
                    win = true;}

            else{win = false;
            }
```

And action code:

```
  public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
            //one more move has gone by, calculate player turn + player letter
            move++;
            if (move % 2 == 0) {
                    player = 1; letter = "X";
            }else{
                    player = 2; letter = "O";
            }

            playergo.setText("It is player " + player + "'s go!");

            //set square letter to player's letter, disable square so no further moves can be made there
            for (int i=0; i<=8; i++){
                    if (e.getSource() == square[i]){
                            square[i].setText(letter);
                            square[i].setEnabled(false);
                    }
            }
```

Full pastebin code [here](http://pastebin.com/JwXM4Vjt). Thank you all in advance!!!

Comment: Sorry - it's `0-1-2 ||

3-4-5 ||

6-7-8`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are not using if/else in your win conditions, you will always check the last `if`, and if that resolves to `false`, you will set `win = false`

Comment: +1. Equally problematic: if the last `if`-condition resolves to `true`, you will set `win = true`. Which is intended, I'm sure, but it's a bug anyway, because none of the `if`-conditions has anything to do with the actual win-conditions for Tic-Tac-Toe. :-/

Comment: Ok. So how would you suggest I go about changing this? Do I need to rewrite the whole section or just tweak one or two things?

Comment: @Sphyxx: I suggest you rewrite the whole section, factoring it out into two methods: a method `isWinningRow(String a, String b, String c)` that returns `true` if its arguments are either `XXX` or `OOO`, and a method `containsWinningRow(JButton[] grid)` that returns `true` if any of the rows/columns/diagonals elicits a `true` from `isWinningRow`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like so( in psuedo-code)

```
int winPositions[][] = { {0,1,2}, {3,4,5}, {6,7,8}, //horizontal
                         {0,3,6}, {1,4,7}, {2,5,8}, //vertical
                         {0,4,8}, {2,4,6} }; //diagnol 

for i = 0 to winPosition.size
  int positions[] = winPosition[i]; //know its size is 3
  bool hasWon = board[ positions[i] ] == board[ positions[i+1] ] && board[positions[i+1]] == board[positions[i+2]];
  if(hasWon) return true;
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't understand the { positions[i] == positions[i+1] == positions[i+2] }. How does this cross-reference and check the win conditions?

Comment: The `board[...]` would contain the 'X's or 'O's and we use the position as index. In your case, it would be `square[ positions[i]] == square[positions[i+1] ... `

Comment: Ah okay I see, so the [i] refers to the win line condition and the second [] refers to the 3 positions in the winning line array. Gotcha. Ty!!